# I'm passing my model but still get an error System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, null

I have been stuck in this error for days and I can't understand why, I'm pretty sure I'm passing my model correctly.

Here is my code:

Controller method:

```
public ActionResult EditaUsuario(int id)
{
    List<usuario> user = new List<usuario>();
    string sql = "query..."

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion))
    {
        // ...
    }

    List<estudiante> estudiante = new List<estudiante>();
    string sqlEstudiante = "query...";

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion))
    {
        // ...
    }

    ViewModelUsuarioEstudiante viewModel = new ViewModelUsuarioEstudiante()
            {
                user = user,
                student = estudiante
            };

    if (id >= 0)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(viewModel);
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    } 
}
```

Model class:

```
namespace Cursos.Models
{
    public class ViewModelUsuarioEstudiante
    {
        public List<usuario> user { get; set; }
        public List<estudiante> student { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Cursos.Models.ViewModelUsuarioEstudiante 

<form action="@Url.Action("EditaUsuario", "Usuario")" method="post">

     <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" class="form-control" value="@Model.user[0].id" />

     <!-- Role input -->
     <select class="form-select" name="rol" aria-label="Default select example" required>
         <option value="@Model.user[0].rol_id">@Model.user[0].roles.rol</option>
         <option value="ADMIN">ADMIN</option>
         <option value="CLIENTE">CLIENTE</option>
     </select>

     <br />

     <!-- Name input -->
     <div class="form-outline mb-4">
         <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control" value="@Model.user[0].nombre" required />
         <label class="form-label" for="nombre">Nombre</label>
     </div>

     @if (Model.user[0].estudiante == true) 
     { 
         <div class="form-outline mb-4">
             <input type="text" name="matricula" id="matricula" value="@Model.student[0].matricula" class="form-control" />
             <label class="form-label" for="matricula">Matricula</label>
         </div>

         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-8">
                 <!-- Name input -->
                 <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                     <input type="text" name="carrera" id="carrera" value="@Model.student[0].carrera" class="form-control" />
                     <label class="form-label" for="carrera">Carrera o Programa</label>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
                 <!-- Lastname input -->
                 <select class="form-select" name="nivelEstudios" id="estudios"  aria-label="Default select example">
                     <option value="@Model.student[0].nivelEstudios">@Model.student[0].nivelEstudios</option>
                     <option value="TSU">TSU</option>
                     <option value="INGENIERIA">INGENIERIA</option>
                 </select>
             </div>
        </div>
    }

    <!-- Submit button -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-3">Actualizar Usuario</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block mb-3">Cancelar</button>
</form>
```

Whenever I click on the update user button the error pops on the first tag with the id of the user

I was thinking of using something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" class="form-control" 
       value="@Model.user !=null ? Model.user[0].id : ' ' " />
```

Comment: `Model` is `null` means that it not passed correctly to the view: the `Model` is empty, not the `user` list is empty. Add code showing how your prepare data model and pass it to the view, please.

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio and check log file that can be found in the explorer under Management.  Even better test all you queries in SSMS to make sure they work before using in c#.  The error messages are much better in SSMS than in c#.